# Service workers: Invalidate specific cached responses

Tags: javascript, caching, web, service-worker

I'm wanting to invalidate a previously cached `GET` from my service worker when a `POST`, `PUT`, or `DELETE` to the same url or any url of a resource or collection 'under' it happens, for example:

let's say I cache `/subscriptions` and later on I do a `POST` to `/subscriptions` to add a new subscription, or say I `PUT` to `/subscriptions/243` to update an existing subscription. 
This means that my cached subscriptions collection is now stale data and I want to delete it from my cache so the next request will go to the server.

I've thought of two options, where I'm not sure either are possible:

**Can I use a Regexp in the `caches.match()` call?**

This way I could just match the parent collection piece of the requested url with keys found in the cache.

**Can I get the keys of each cached data response?**

If so, I could just loop through each response and see if the key meets my criteria for deleting it.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a RegExp or anything other than string matching (optionally [ignoring query parameters](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/cache-query-options#ignoresearch)) when doing a lookup via `caches.match()`.

I'd recommend the second approach, in which you open a named cache, [get its keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/keys), and then filter for the ones you care about. It's not that much code, and looks fairly nice with `await`/`async`:

```
async function deleteCacheEntriesMatching(cacheName, regexp) {
  const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
  const cachedRequests = await cache.keys();
  // request.url is a full URL, not just a path, so use an appropriate RegExp!
  const requestsToDelete = cachedRequests.filter(request => request.url.match(regexp));
  return Promise.all(requestsToDelete.map(request => cache.delete(request)));
}

// Call it like:
await deleteCacheEntriesMatching('my-cache', new RegExp('/subscriptions'));
```